# RuntimeError: 'v4l2loopback' backend: std::exception

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, stderr, v4l2loopback

I'm getting above error when I'm trying to execute following piece of code:

```
import pyvirtualcam
import numpy as np

with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=20) as cam:
    print(f'Using virtual camera: {cam.device}')
    frame = np.zeros((cam.height, cam.width, 3), np.uint8)  # RGB
    while True:
        frame[:] = cam.frames_sent % 255  # grayscale animation
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
```

I'm running this on raspberry pi (Kernel version: 5.10 and raspberrypi-kernel-headers version  is 1:1.20210527-1).

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualcam/camera.py", line 219, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('\n'.join(errors))
  RuntimeError: 'v4l2loopback' backend: std::exception
```

**Solved:**

v4l2loopback was crashed for some reason which caused this issue, Following lines at the beginning of the code fixed the issue.

```
 import os

 if "raspberrypi" in str(os.uname()):
            os.system("sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback")
            os.system("sudo modprobe v4l2loopback")
```

Comment: Worth specifying a question e.g. "How do I fix this?" or "what is causing this?" or "is this a v4l2loopback backend bug?"

Comment: The need to yo-yo the module hints that you confused it last time. Didn't close?

Comment: "with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=20) as cam:" This should close it automatically in the end, Couldn't figure out what caused that issue yet.